# Matrix form of the system

Tags: matrix-equations

How to represent it as a matrix?

\begin{align}
\dfrac{dx}{dt}&=4x+4y-24,
\\
\dfrac{dy}{dt}&=-8x+16y+60.
\end{align}

Or, at least, how to represent a single equation:

\begin{align}
\dfrac{dx}{dt}&=4x+4y-24,
\end{align}

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{pmatrix}\dot x\\\dot y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4&4\\-8&16\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}-24\\60\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I can add 2x2 matrix to 2x1 matrix?

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}4&4\\-8&16\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}$ is $2\times 1$ matrix.

Comment: @mfl, thanks.  .

Comment: Off topic, but why you divid**ed** exactly $dy$ by $dx$, but not vice versa?

Comment: @АртурКлочко: You can also compute $dx/dy$. But neither of these equation gives an easy ODE to solve.

Comment: Ok, and If I want to get the eigenvalues of this system to determine type of the singularity point, considering the fact, that this system is a linearization of nonlinear system, near some point, what I have to do?

Comment: Just compute the eigenvalue of $\begin{pmatrix}4&4\\-8&16\end{pmatrix}$ ;-)

Comment: Oh I thought You didn't answer. But as I read, to find an eigenvalues of nonhomogeneous system, I need, at first find a homogeneous solution, then add a nonhomogeneous solution, or something like that, no? I honestly, made a research, I have read a lot of articles, but I didn't understand..

Comment: That's all, I understood, thank You

Answer (score 1):

It is a non-homogeneous linear system:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\dot x\\ \dot y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4&4\\ -8&16\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\  y\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}-24\\ 60\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: If I want to get the eigenvalues of this system to determine type of the singularity point, considering the fact, that this system is a linearization of nonlinear system, near some point, what I have to do?